# AWS API Gateway: How is 4XX and 5XX errors logged in cloudwatch? Example find Status Code 413, Request Entity too large error is logged in Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am getting a Status Code 413, Request Entity too large error while calling the api gateway->Lambda Setup. i wanted to quickly check what time this error happened and find it in Cloudwatch.
I see the errors are 4XX and 5XX in my API monitoring but cant get into details of the error. There can be multiple error example 402,413 etc and there is no easy way to get all the 4XX error detailed logs.

Need a easy query to go through these error.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out the following Loginsights query on your apigateway logs can find all errors for a particular status. The following screenshot shows all requests with status as 200. You can modify as below query for 4XX and 5XX or any particular error

1. All 4XX errors search:  "status: 4"
2. All 5XX errors search: "status: 5"
3. All 413 errors search:  "status: 413"

[image]